# What's the type of Map that convered through json to Map with Gson?

Tags: java, dictionary, gson

I conver `LinkedHashMap<Integer, Double>` to json string with Gson to store in database, after withdrawing from database conver to `LinkedHashMap`.

```
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put(100, 0.5);
    map.put(102, 0.2);
    map.put(99, 0.8);

    String result = new Gson().toJson(map);

    System.out.println(result);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, Double>>(){}.getType();
    Map<Integer, Double> resMap = gson.fromJson(result, mapType);
```

So, I am confused about the resMap, is it a type of LinkedHashMap? Or I should do like `LinkedHashMap<Integer, Double> resMap = ...`?

Answer (score 1):

It would be a LinkedHashMap

Check from this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

LinkedHashMap<Integer, Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put(100, 0.5);
map.put(102, 0.2);
map.put(99, 0.8);

String result = new Gson().toJson(map);

System.out.println(result);

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, Double>>(){}.getType();
Map<Integer, Double> resMap = gson.fromJson(result, mapType);
System.out.println(resMap.getClass());
}
```

Output of this:

```
{"100":0.5,"102":0.2,"99":0.8}
class java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

Comment: But why it will be a LinkedHashMap? I mean, when conver to Map I just use the `Map<Integer, Double> ` not the `LinkedHashMap<Integer, Double>`. Is it related to the original Map that I conver to json?

Comment: Good point, I was wondering the same while writing this.  But it is not related to the original map type i guess. I don't know why is it a `LinkedHashMap`